# Unable to Query SetupAuditTrail Object

Tags: community, rest-api, setup-audit-log

I am Unable to query "`SetupAuditTrail`" through Rest call.

When I made "`SELECT Id FROM SetupAuditTrail Where CreatedDate>2019-12-25T15:00:00Z`"query, I got

> *RESPONSE: Object type 'SetupAuditTrail' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity
> name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
> appropriate names*
>
> *RESPONSE CODE: 400*
>
> *ERROR CODE: INVALID_TYPE*

I can see Audit logs in my UI. And when I tried to download these logs through an API  got this. Please, could anyone tell me where I am wrong or what should I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE.

`SetupAuditTrail` is valid for SOQL query.

Just make sure that you are executing the SOQL in the format applicable for `GET` REST call

The URI must be in this format:

```
/vXX.X/query/?q=SOQL query
```

Example of request via curl:

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

So for querying `SetupAuditTrail` the URI will be similar to this:

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/query/?q=select+Action,CreatedById,CreatedDate,DelegateUser,Display,Id,ResponsibleNamespacePrefix,Section+from+SetupAuditTrail+Where+CreatedDate>2019-12-25T15:00:00Z
```

The `INVALID_TYPE` error could be resulting from a permission issue, ensure that the user profile executing the request has "View Setup and Configuration" which is [required for viewing audit trail history](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_monitorsetup.htm).

References:

[API REST Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm)

[REST Execute SOQL query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using SOQL query only.
The URI that I am using is `https://Instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+SetupAuditTrail++Where+CreatedDate>2019-12-25T15:00:00Z`. After querying this, I got the above response along with `status code: 400 and "errorCode": "INVALID_TYPE"`

Comment: @trinadh could you try calling the URI to query from `Account` object and provide the result ?

Comment: I got 200 response code for Account Object.

Comment: @trinadh it might be a permission issue why query on `SetupAuditTrail` is not working. with which type of user profile are you executing the REST call on `SetupAuditTrail` ?

Comment: @trinadh I was able to reproduce the `INVALID_TYPE` error by executing REST call with a user which does not have "View setup and configuration" permission. see updated answer for more details

Comment: @trinadh can you try setting latest API version v47.0

Comment: @Shamina It is because of the user with which I am trying to query don't have `view setup and configuration` permission. Thank You so much for your help. After adding the permission it is working good.